# Port forwarding works for friends that have the same ISP as me, but It doesn't work for anyone with a different ISP?

Tags: router, isp, minecraft

I'm trying to host a Minecraft server at home for friends, and it's not going well.

I have done the following:

- Set up the server
- Allowed the server through the firewall
- Configured my router to allow port forwarding on the appropriate ports

My problem: Friend 1 is on the same ISP as me, and can connect to my server using my external IP address. Friend 2 is on a different ISP, and cannot connect to my server using my external IP address.

I've made a simple diagram to hopefully demonstrate my problem:
[image]
What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: It's possible your ISP has its border devices configured to block those ports.  You might want to contact their support.

Comment: How did you determine your public IP address? If you just looked at your router's administration UI for its WAN port IP address, it might not be an actual public IP address; it might still be an RFC 1918 private address if your ISP runs a NAT gateway at their level (this is known as a "Carrier-Grade NAT" or CGNAT). Use a public site like https://whatismyipaddress.com to determine what the public Internet sees as your address. If it's different than what your router's admin UI reports as its WAN port IP address, then you are likely behind a CGNAT.